# Me either OR Me neither? MW Collegiate Dictionary says Me Either is correct in this example

Tags: grammar

Me either OR Me neither? MW Collegiate Dictionary says Me Either is correct.

Shouldn't it be "Me neither" in this example?

"I didn't like the movie." 
"Me either."

Perhaps "either" is truly correct because the sentence equates to "I didn't either." "I didn't neither" would be incorrect because it's a double negative. Your thoughts? Should it be "Me either" or "Me neither" in that example?

Comment: How do you check this site to search for already provided responses to avert duplicate queries?

Comment: @whippoorwill When you write your question title, the system scans for possible duplicates. The one nominated is in that list, and was probably top before **this** question was posted.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I never want to post repeat questions. I truly value the staff of professionals here. There is no grammar site quite like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are communicating a NEGATIVE idea, you should include a negative form, thus - **NEITHER** would be a **better** and the most correct form in many cases.